# Multiple Colliders on Complex Object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have designed a complex city with thousand of objects like roads, sideways, buidlings, trees, etc. and imported to Unity3d

I want to put colliders over them, so that when player hit them, it should face collision and should not passes though them

Though it has many objects, if i put one by one collider to each object, it will take so much time. Is there any other way i can just select all of them and put collider.

Also, if i select all object and put colliders (Mesh Collider). it is not adding to the object

[image: City]

Please help

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is a limit to the number of triangles that cam make up a mesh collider, consequently, your only option is to put colliders on all of them (it would be best to add these to the prefabs). Alternatively, you could consider taking the oldschool approach and just block off massive areas innacurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Editor Scripting* to the rescue. I would write a tool similar to this example. It uses a [Menu Item](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html) which can be selected via *Window -> Collider Tool*. It then runs our custom method to find all meshes, which we want to add a collider to, then adds one and also logs which GameObjects were changed.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class ColliderTool
{
    [MenuItem("Window/Collider Tool")]
    public static void RunTool()
    {
        List<MeshFilter> meshes = findObjectsThatNeedColliders();

        for (int i = 0; i < meshes.Count; i++) 
        {
            GameObject go = meshes[i].gameObject;

            // Add a collider to each mesh and record the undo step.
            MeshCollider collider = Undo.AddComponent<MeshCollider>(go);

            // Use the existing mesh as the collider mesh.
            collider.sharedMesh = meshes[i].sharedMesh;

            Debug.Log("Added a new collider on: " + go.name, go);
        }

        Debug.Log("Done");
    }

    private static List<MeshFilter> findObjectsThatNeedColliders()
    {
        // This list will be filled with all meshes, which require a collider.
        List<MeshFilter> meshesWithoutCollider = new List<MeshFilter>();

        // Get all meshes in the scene. This only returns active ones.
        // Maybe we also need inactive ones, which we can get via GetRootGameObjects and GetComponent.
        MeshFilter[] allMeshes = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<MeshFilter>();

        foreach(MeshFilter mesh in allMeshes)
        {
            if(mesh.GetComponent<Collider>() == null)
                meshesWithoutCollider.Add(mesh);
        }

        return meshesWithoutCollider;
    }
}
```

You might need more complex rules about which objects require a collider and which type it should be, but a simple tool can still save you a lot of time before hand tweaking everything.

You should also consider making this selection based. The [Selection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection.html) class can give you a list of all selected objects. Some ideas:

- Add a MeshCollider to all selected objects, if one doesn't already exist.
- Add a BoxCollider to selected objects and scale it to an approximate size depending on the transform size or bounding box of the MeshRenderer.

My solution is based on your question about how to add a collider to many objects in a large scene. However, this might not be the overall best solution. Maybe too many MeshColliders hurt physics performance. You will most likely want to approximate most of the colliders with boxes and spheres, but of course you can still write a tool to help you with that.